# Postgres Auto-Create records in table, on insert in another table

Tags: postgresql

Completely new to Postgres. Need to be able to automatically insert several rows in a "Folders" table upon creation of a record in the "Companies" table.

The idea is that when an Company is created, the standard set of documents folders are auto created.
Several of the rows are 'sub-folders' and as such will require the id of the parent folder.

The SQL statements for the Inserts are(with noted Parent folder ID needs):

```
// Administration
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Administration', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:50:49.579553', '2022-03-19 15:50:49.579553', '');
    // Get Insert ID
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Agreements', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{AdministrationFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:53:24.412457', '2022-03-19 15:53:24.412457', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Licensing', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{AdministrationFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'QBR & Meeting Notes', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{AdministrationFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Reports', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{AdministrationFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '');
// Knowlege Base
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Knowledge Base', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:51:53.006775', '2022-03-19 15:51:53.006775', '');
    // Get Insert ID
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Configurations', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{KnowledgeBaseFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'How-To', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{KnowledgeBaseFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Diagrams & Photos', NULL, {CompanyID}, '{KnowledgeBaseFolderID}', '2022-03-19 15:53:05.517208', '2022-03-19 15:53:05.517208', '');


// Other Folders
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'SOPs', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:05.152894', '2022-03-19 15:52:05.152894', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Projects', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:15.818519', '2022-03-19 15:52:15.818519', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Strategy', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:28.388031', '2022-03-19 15:52:28.388031', '');
INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, '>Inbox', NULL, {CompanyID}, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:50:26.174575', '2022-03-19 15:51:03.30431', '');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: folders exist only in a filesystem not sql so i don't get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The database has a table for categorizing information under 'folders'. So each document is assigned a 'folder'.

Comment: it is hard to understand which information must be transfered to another table, of which we don't know the design. Take a look at after insert trigger or

Comment: Note that it's more efficient to run a single INSERT that inserts multiple rows, rater than multiple INSERTs that insert only a single row.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to accomplish this:

The key was the `RETURNING  INTO` to handle the inserting of the 'child' folders.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."function_create_folders"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    admin_id integer;
    kb_id integer;
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Administration', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:50:49.579553', '2022-03-19 15:50:49.579553', 'Articles and documents supporting our handling/management of this company.') RETURNING id INTO admin_id;
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Agreements', NULL, new.id, admin_id, '2022-03-19 15:53:24.412457', '2022-03-19 15:53:24.412457', 'Agreements we have with this company');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Licensing', NULL, new.id, admin_id, '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', 'Licenses and supporting documentation for this company');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'QBR & Meeting Notes', NULL, new.id, admin_id, '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', 'QBR and Meeting notes.');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Reports', NULL, new.id, admin_id, '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', '2022-03-19 15:53:31.780207', 'Reporting respository.');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Knowledge Base', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:51:53.006775', '2022-03-19 15:51:53.006775', 'Company specific details, and guides.')  RETURNING id INTO kb_id;   
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Configurations', NULL, new.id, kb_id, '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', 'Notes and Details, about Assets and Networks for this Company.');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'How-To', NULL, new.id, kb_id, '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', '2022-03-19 15:52:54.092854', 'How-To and Guides for solving customer specific issues.');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Diagrams & Photos', NULL, new.id, kb_id, '2022-03-19 15:53:05.517208', '2022-03-19 15:53:05.517208', 'Diagrams and Pictures related to this Company');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'SOPs', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:05.152894', '2022-03-19 15:52:05.152894', 'Specific SOPs related to this company. (i.e.. New User Onboarding Process, Change Control Process)');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Projects', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:15.818519', '2022-03-19 15:52:15.818519', 'Notes and details about projects for this company.  ** Create Separate Sub-Folders Per Project **');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, 'Strategy', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:52:28.388031', '2022-03-19 15:52:28.388031', 'Guides and Articles about both the customers internal strategy, as well as our strategy for working with them.');
    INSERT INTO "public"."folders"("account_id", "name", "icon", "company_id", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES (1, '>Inbox', NULL, new.id, NULL, '2022-03-19 15:50:26.174575', '2022-03-19 15:51:03.30431', 'In development articles should be saved here.');
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100


CREATE TRIGGER trig_create_folders
     AFTER INSERT ON companies
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_create_folders();
```